# SOS composer will not run. Unfixable php.ini files?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've been trying to build out a test app and I can't even get past the initial start. I'm using PHP and composer to create this project using the `composer create-project Laravel/Laravel example-app`

And I continuously get this error.

```
Problem 1
  - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.13.5] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.15.1].
  - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
  - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.15.1] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0].
  - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
  - league/flysystem-local 3.15.0 require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
  - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.13.5].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
```

I've followed the guides and edited the php.ini files numerous times and I have uninstalled everything multiple times. I've followed all of the guides I can find to no success. Any help would be a god send. I've even run the command ignoring these requirements and it still isn't working.

Comment: Read the error message. `laravel/framework` can't be installed because `league/flysystem` can't be installed.  `league/flysystem` can't be installed because `league/flysystem-local` can't be installed. `league/flysystem-local` can't be installed because you do not have the `fileinfo` extension enabled in your `php.ini`.

Comment: Solution: Enable the `fileinfo` extension in your `php.ini`. If it doesn't show up when you do `php -m`, then you do not have it enabled.

Comment: Adding to what @IGP already said: the error message also says that `league/mime-type-detection` requires PHP 7 and you’re using PHP 8.